# Kernel Configuration Fragment not applying

Tags: buildroot, kbuild

I am attempting to add a linux kernel configuration fragment file (`linux-1024MB-frags.config`) into my build. Inside the fragment file I have set, `CONFIG_HIGHMEM=y`.

In my buildroot .config I have enabled,

`BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_MYPATH)/board/common/linux-1024MB-frags.config"`

When I do `linux-dirclean && linux-configure` I see the following output,

```
Merging /home/labuser/buildroot/trunk/board/common/linux-1024MB-frags.config
#
# merged configuration written to /home/labuser/buildroot/trunk/buildroot/output/build/linux-xilinx-v2017.1/.config (needs make)
#
```

Inspecting the new .config file shows that `CONFIG_HIGHMEM` is still not set.

If I set `CONFIG_HIGHMEM` in the main defconfig that I am using for the kernel (the one defined by `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE`) and repeat the make steps I see that the `CONFIG_HIGHMEM` option IS set.